# ClosesableHttpClient close optimality

Tags: java, http, optimization, apache-httpclient-4.x

I defined my own class `RestClient` that acts like an interface for rest methods calls.

An object of RestClient class it's instantiated only once and used multiple times for different methods. (`doGet() doPost()` etc.)

There are two possible solutions:

**1.**

```
class RestClient {
   private CloseableHttpClient client;

   public void doGet(String URI){
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URI);
      try (CloseableHttpResponse resp = client.execute(request)) {

   }
}
```

**2.**

```
class RestClient {

   public void doGet(String URI) {
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URI);
try(CloseableHttpClient client = createClient(); CloseableHttpResponse resp = client.execute(request)){
    } catch(Exception e){
    } finally { close(client);}

}
```

My question is:

Is it better to have an attribute of type `CloseableHttpClient` and create this client only once in the `RestClient` class constructor, or create a different client each time I make a call to one of the methods and after each call close the client?

Comment: If there is a better solution I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: As I see from [Apache Docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html), chp 2.4, they are using single instance of CloseableHttpClient to run multiple threads which will execute one HttpGet request per thread. So probably, creating multiple clients is the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

HttpClient instances are expensive to create. They ought to be re-used even if used infrequently. Creating a new instance of HttpClient per each request execution is the worst anti-pattern in HttpClient usage.